# First letter in input field shows and the remaining letters as invisible like ****** how to do in javascript and typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

In Python

```
word = 'hello'
word[1] + '*' * len(word[1:])
```

the output was 'e****'

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this, using [`String.prototype.repeat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat):

```js
const word = 'hello';
const res = word[1] + '*'.repeat(word.length - 1);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Should it not be `word[0]`? I know OP has similar code, but it should he *h\*\*\*\** in my understanding

Comment: Initially, I did it with `word[0]` but then realized OP has `word[1]` so I changed it

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve it by running this code:

```
const word = "foo";
const res = word[0] + "*".repeat(word.length - 1);
console.log(res);
```

It will get the first character of the word and will add * as many times as the length of the original word minus the first character.

Edit:
[Demo with input](https://jsfiddle.net/WimStienstra/sqLmkwy7/37/)